# Integral solutions to the equation $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{15}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{15}}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots, radicals

> Find all integral solutions to the equation 
>   $$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{15}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{15}}.$$

Clearly, $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{n}$, so $n\geq 0$, and the equation becomes
$$\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{15}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{15}}.$$
Squaring both sides (which I am aware may introduce additional solutions) gives
$$n=2a-2\sqrt{a^2-15}.$$
We require $a+\sqrt{15}\geq 0$ and $a-\sqrt{15}\geq 0$, so $a\geq 4$. Is it possible to find an upper bound for $a$, or bounds on $n$?

Rearranging and squaring again (which may also introduce superfluous solutions) gives
$$4a^2-4an+n^2=4a^2-60,$$
or 
$$n^2-4an+60=0.$$
Perhaps now writing 
$$n(4a-n)=60$$
helps, since we know $n,4a-n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and the integral factors of $60$ are $1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-10,-12,-15,-20,-30,-60$. Since I have already shown $a$ and $n$ are non-negative, the negative factors can be excluded.

Moreover, $n$ must be even, since if $n$ is odd, both $n$ and $4a-n$ are odd, so their product cannot be $60$.

From here it is tedious (but easy) to find the solutions and then double check that they satisfy the original equation.

> **Questions:** 1) Does this solution appear to be correct?
>
> 2) Is there an easier solution? I would welcome any suggestions for alternative solutions.

Comment: You could use the quadratic formula to calculate $n$'s.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $n=2a\pm2\sqrt{a^2-15}$ - is that what you mean? I already knew earlier (in my 4th line) that $n=2a-2\sqrt{a^2-15}$

Comment: But if you want $n$ to be an integer, you can check which factors of $60$ make $a^2-15$ to be square.  If you're smart about modular arithmetic, you can cut down several of the options right away.

Comment: Looks right, but as Michael Burr suggested, it's probably a little less work to find the $a$ such that $a^2-15$ is a square, i.e. write $a^2 - b^2 = 15$ with $0 < b < a$.

Comment: Must $a$ be an integer?

Comment: @ConnorHarris Yes

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I think I understand what you mean now. $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and the only factorizations of $15$ are $1\times 15$ and $3\times 5$ and since $b>0$, $a+b>a-b$, so either $a=8,b=7$ or $a=4, b=1$. From here I can find $(n,a)=(2,8)$ or $(6,4)$.

Comment: @woofy `Moreover, n must be even` And moreover, $n$ cannot be a multiple of $4$ since $60$ is not divisible by $16$. This only leaves $2, 6, 10, 30$ to check, which is not a lot.